# Transistor code meaning

Tags: transistors

I have this transistor with the **E 8G** and the three dots on them, can anybody tell me what its meaning is? Does it have to do with the manufacturer?

[image]

Comment: The part in question is a Sanyo 2SB544

Comment: It's usually a date code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, it's a [Sanyo](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/100496/SANYO/2SB544.html) (probably, they were the original manufacturer according to the Transistor Manual) [2SB544](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/100496/SANYO/2SB544.html), a 25V PNP general purpose transistor with the usual Japanese B-C-E pinout.

These ones are the 2nd lowest (third highest) hFE bin- between 100 and 200 at 2V Vce and 50mA Ic. That is denoted by the 'E'.

The other characters are probably date code, lot code, manufacturing site, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a PNP BJT with part number 2SB544.
The E 8G is likely some kind of manufacturer sorting code.
Could be a date code, hfe classification, etc